# Creating cumulative friction map

Tags: python, grass-gis, flood, grass.script

I am looking at bottom friction (Manning's n) values in relation to storm surge as large volumes of water flow over a surface.

In order to calculate total head loss occurring as water passes from the original water's edge to the final flooding extent, I must somehow figure out a way to account for cumulative losses. Is there a way I can create a raster map containing the cumulative (or average) Manning's n values over which the water has traveled?

In other words, with the accumulation of friction starting from the original water's edge, the first cell would contain its own Manning's n value (I will call this n1). Moving away from the water's edge, the next cell will be n1+n2. The next cell away from the water will be n1+n2+n3 and so on.

Below is a script I have created for making a cumulative Manning's n map for a small (121-cell) sample raster of Manning's values. The sample raster is named manningWithWater and this is done using r.buffer. The buffer starts from the raster called falseWater, which is artificial water values I have added to the Manning's raster. The script works but is inefficient; this took 22 seconds on my tiny sample raster and would use up quite a bit of memory while processing a regularly-sized raster.

```
import grass.script as grass

def main():
    x = range(100,700,50)
    numString = ""
    for num in x:
        numString = numString + str(num) + ","
    numString = numString[:-1]
    grass.run_command('r.buffer',
        overwrite=True,
        input="falseWater@PERMANENT",
        output="falseWaterBuffer",
        distances=numString,
        units="feet")
    totalBuffers=grass.read_command('r.describe',
        map="falseWaterBuffer")
    maxBuffer=int(totalBuffers.split("-")[-1])
    finalExpression=""
    for n in range(2,maxBuffer+1):
        grass.mapcalc(
            "$output=if($buffer==$bandNumber,$manningWithWater,null())",
            overwrite=True,
            buffer="falseWaterBuffer@PERMANENT",
            output="band"+str(n),
            bandNumber=n,
            manningWithWater="manningWithWater@PERMANENT")
        grass.run_command('r.grow.distance',
            overwrite=True,
            input="band{0}@PERMANENT".format(n),
            value="band{0}Grown".format(n))
        grass.mapcalc(
            "$output=if($buffer>=$bandNumber,$bandGrown,0)",
            overwrite=True,
            output="band{0}Add".format(n),
            buffer="falseWaterBuffer@PERMANENT",
            bandNumber=n,
            bandGrown="band{0}Grown@PERMANENT".format(n))
        finalExpression=finalExpression+"band{0}Add@PERMANENT+".format(n)
    finalExpression=finalExpression[:-1]
    grass.mapcalc(
        "cumulativeN={0}".format(finalExpression),
        overwrite=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How are your Manning's coefficients determined? Are you at all familiar with HEC-RAS or flowpath modeling? I would start thinking about raster-based spatial statistics (Manning n) along flowpath lines and/or flow accumulations. A hydrologist might be inclined to model the reach historically/empirically and arrive at Manning #s that way.

Comment: Assigning Manning values is still far from calculating cumulative losses. The Mannning value has a meaning only within the hydraulic equations that use it to estimate the head losses. From a hydraulic point of view, there is no interest in having a cumulative Manning's n value (n1+n2+n3)

Comment: @CrystallineEntity I am using Manning's coefficients from the USGS National Land Cover Database. I am not very familiar with HEC-RAS and I am somewhat familiar with flowpath modeling. However I am working on creating a novel storm surge model for use with [ADCIRC](http://adcirc.org/) so I don't believe I will be able to utilize HEC-RAS. I have considered looking at flowpath lines but I have been unable to think of a way to do this efficiently for storm surge since most of these flowpath operations in GRASS seem to concern rainwater runoff.

Comment: @Marco I agree that cumulative Manning's n values by themselves don't have hydraulic meaning. However I am working on a real-time storm surge model which needs to operate quickly based on input data from [ADCIRC](http://adcirc.org/). This cumulative map will allow me to pre-compute as much as possible and later apply averaging techniques which will keep the model's run time to a minimum.

Comment: If your app, while doing something complex with a lot of data, uses "quite a bit of memory" (but which does not exceed the actual RAM on the system), then it could just be a well coded app, using RAM to reduce disk I/O.

Answer (score 0):

`r.watershed` has a `flow` input and an `accumulation` output. Pass in the manning raster for `flow` and the `accumulation` will be the "cumulative ... Manning's n values over which the water has traveled" that you seek. You can run it a second time with no `flow` input, and then `accumulation` is the number of cells. You can use that to get the average `n` value.